# I've been mining with geth but my balance is still 0. Why?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

Today I started mining ether on the main network and I see new blocks being processed in the console but my balance is still zero ether. Why?
This is the geth console output:

```
I0214 20:15:47.234020    1216 state_object.go:184] c2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d
42ebbcf3512: #0 1971300000000000 (+ 1971300000000000)
I0214 20:15:47.236020    1216 state_object.go:192] 7abc7e855f89634292f77433744f3
9cb7012d8bd: #10 23234021130000000000 (- 1050000000000000)
I0214 20:15:47.237020    1216 statedb.go:264] (+) 87cefcd85849581188da109821c928
b4c0932117
I0214 20:15:47.237020    1216 state_object.go:192] 7abc7e855f89634292f77433744f3
9cb7012d8bd: #11 6697569040000000000 (- 16536452090000000000)
I0214 20:15:47.237020    1216 state_object.go:184] 87cefcd85849581188da109821c92
8b4c0932117: #0 16536452090000000000 (+ 16536452090000000000)
I0214 20:15:47.237020    1216 state_transition.go:226] VM call err: <nil>
I0214 20:15:47.238020    1216 state_object.go:184] 7abc7e855f89634292f77433744f3
9cb7012d8bd: #11 6697569040000000000 (+ 0)
I0214 20:15:47.238020    1216 state_object.go:184] 7abc7e855f89634292f77433744f3
9cb7012d8bd: #11 6697569040000000000 (+ 0)
I0214 20:15:47.238020    1216 state_object.go:184] c2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d
42ebbcf3512: #0 3021300000000000 (+ 1050000000000000)
I0214 20:15:47.240020    1216 state_object.go:192] 2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d1
64135398226: #174744 2635781682982219387398 (- 4500000000000000)
I0214 20:15:48.688103    1216 state_object.go:192] 2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d1
64135398226: #174745 2634194142482219387398 (- 1587540500000000000)
I0214 20:15:48.689103    1216 state_object.go:184] cd424c53f5dc7d22cdff536309c24
ad87a97e6af: #205 1587540505153155872 (+ 1587540500000000000)
I0214 20:15:48.689103    1216 state_transition.go:226] VM call err: <nil>
I0214 20:15:48.689103    1216 state_object.go:184] 2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d1
64135398226: #174745 2634197592482219387398 (+ 3450000000000000)
I0214 20:15:48.690103    1216 state_object.go:184] 2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d1
64135398226: #174745 2634197592482219387398 (+ 0)
I0214 20:15:48.690103    1216 state_object.go:184] c2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d
42ebbcf3512: #0 4071300000000000 (+ 1050000000000000)
I0214 20:15:48.691103    1216 state_object.go:184] c2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d
42ebbcf3512: #0 5004071300000000000 (+ 5000000000000000000)
I0214 20:15:48.692103    1216 worker.go:570] commit new work on block 1003783 wi
th 3 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.4680839s
```

My ether adress is 0xc2a2c4df47a4fef4a023139fb570d42ebbcf3512 and geth has added some to my adress, but the balance is still 0. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the data provided you are indeed mining, but at the current difficulty level you will need significant GPU power to solo-mine a new block. Join a mining pool.

Comment: Yes but how can we join a pool with geth??  For a reason i cant run ethminer on my ubuntu 20 so geth is the onlything i can use

Answer (score 4):

It's always useful to use a mining calculator to know how long it would take you on average to mine a new block (and how much profit you'll get it you're after that)

You can check your hashrate on Geth using this command, the result is in H/s (Hash operations per second).

```
>eth.hashrate
712000
```

**Here are a couple calculators**

- [Etherscan Mining Calculator](https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator)
- [Badmofo's Ethereum Mining Profitability Calculator](https://badmofo.github.io/ethereum-mining-calculator/)